# node js module not found for directory of tape tests

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, tap

I have the following structure:

```
src/examples/test_file.js
src/test/example.test.js
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./test/*.test.js"
  },
```

I have tape installed via `npm install tape --save`

I run `npm test` and i get:

```
> node ./test/*.test.js

module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'c:\src\test\*.test.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:1003:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Per this: https://ci.testling.com/guide/tape

tests on a whole dir should only work with a global install of a node package. How can i get the above to work without globally installing tape?

I am using node 5.4 and windows 10

EDIT:

This works fine for me on Mac, and works fine on the linux build server. I am assuming its windows related

Comment: Have one main test file `main.test.js` and have it run all the other test files with `require`'s. `node` can't run more than one file. It's looking for a file literally named `*.test.js`.

Comment: @usandfriends how can i set up that other file to run all the other tests?

Answer (score 1):

```
  "scripts": {
       "test": "tape ./test/*.test.js"
     },
```

try updating your script statement using a call to 'tape', instead of 'node'
npm will find tape in the local install at ./node_moduels/.bin/tape
no need to send through node

Answer (score 0):

> how can i set up that other file to run all the other tests?

One option could be get a list of files in your `test` directory and execute the `node` command for each. Assuming the following is *test.js*, it will run every file matching the pattern you specified.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra')
  //child_process `exec` will let you normal bash-style executions
  //eg, exec('ls') is like programmatically entering the ls command
  //into a terminal window
  , exec = require("child_process").exec;

//callback for after our exec process finishes
function execCallback(error, stdout, stderr) { 
  console.log(stdout);
}
fs.readdir will give us a list of files in the current ('.') directory
var testFiles = fs.readdir('.', function(err, files){
  if (err){
    console.log('error reading files', err);
  }else{
    //use this regex to reduce the list of files to only those which
    //adhere to the pattern you specified using a wildcar "*.test.js"
    files.filter(function(file){
      return /^.*?\.test\.js/.test(file)
    })
    //filter returns the reduced array which is immediately passed to
    //this forEach loop which will use our `exec` command to execute
    //the shell command `node xxxxxx.test.js` for every file in the array we just created
    .forEach(function(testFile){
      exec('node ' + testFile, execCallback);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: i dont understand . Im mostly a java/c# guy so this js is a bit beyond me

Comment: @user3574076 I've added lots of comments to the code. Does that clear up the confusion?

Comment: it does, but where are fs-extra and child_process coming from?

Comment: You need to install them, probably through npm. They'll be added as dependencies to your project, and you can `require` them in any other node file.

Comment: @user3574076 Is this making sense for you now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import all tests in a single file. You can use the `tape` command and globbing (file expansion) of your shell:

```
tape test/**/*.test.js
```

Or use tape's built-in globbing:

```
tape 'test/**/*.test.js'
```

This only works if tape is in your PATH (scripts in package.json adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH). Otherwise you have to provide the path to `tape`:

```
node_modules/.bin/tape test/**/*.test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it only because I don't execute `npm i` in the module folder. You need execute it if you copy it in node_modules folder that don't include those files.